# One to Many Relationship in MS SQL

Tags: sql, one-to-many

I have a table with 49 unique `Item_Classes` and a few hundred unique `Customer_Ids`.

When I query `Customer_ID` and `Item_Class` I only get the `Item_Classes` that each customer has purchased.

I would like to attach every Unique `Item_Class` to every unique `Customer_ID` regardless of whether they have purchased that `Item_Class` or not.

The result should show 49 of the same `Customer_Id` with 49 different unique `Item_Classes` attached to it.

*Note:* This needs to be accomplished without write access to the database.

Comment: Sample data as DDL+DML, desired results and current attempt, please.

Comment: In SQL, getting a one-to-many relationship is accomplished using a "left join".

Comment: Where's your query?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1):

You're describing a Cartesian join of customers and items, e.g.:

```
select *
from
    (select distinct Customer_ID from yourTable) as a,
    (select distinct Item_Class from yourTable) as b;
```

Comment: Please do not use implicit joins. Explicit joins are a part of ANSI-SQL over 25 years now. Also, a cross join would not get the result the OP has described. btw, downvote is not mine.